# Collapse rows with same identifier and columns and retain all values in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that contains several fields related to an identifier but some are disjointed:

```
id    store    manager    fruit    vegetable
1     Grocery1   Joe       apple    NA
1     Grocery1   Joe       lemon    NA
1     Grocery1   Joe       NA       zucchini
2     Grocery2   Amy       orange   NA
2     Grocery2   Amy       NA       asparagus
2     Grocery2   Amy       NA       spinach
3     Grocery3   Bill      NA       NA
```

I want the dataframe to look like:

```
id    store    manager    fruit    vegetable
1     Grocery1   Joe       apple    zucchini
1     Grocery1   Joe       lemon    zucchini
2     Grocery2   Amy       orange   asparagus
2     Grocery2   Amy       orange   spinach
3     Grocery3   Bill      NA       NA
```

Is there a way to easily do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::fill` to `fill` the `NA`, and only keep the non-duplicated rows using `distinct`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(store, manager) %>% 
  fill(fruit, vegetable, .direction = "updown") %>% 
  distinct()

# A tibble: 5 × 5
# Groups:   store, manager [3]
     id store    manager fruit  vegetable
  <int> <chr>    <chr>   <chr>  <chr>    
1     1 Grocery1 Joe     apple  zucchini 
2     1 Grocery1 Joe     lemon  zucchini 
3     2 Grocery2 Amy     orange asparagus
4     2 Grocery2 Amy     orange spinach  
5     3 Grocery3 Bill    NA     NA
```